# Dialogflow(api.ai) with different intents but having similar type of questions confusing api.ai

Tags: java, android, dialogflow-es

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luWhJ.png)I am creating a chat bot android application using api.ai(Dialog flow),I have two intents with similar type of questions.
For ex.
Intent 1:  No_of_user_creating_leads
       Q:  Number of user creating leads today?

Intent 2:  No_of_user_creating_visits
       Q:  Number of user creating leads today?

where user,leads and today is entities.
when i want to ask second number questions it is triggering to first intent instead of second.
is there any way to resolve this problem

Comment: As you've written it - those are identical phrases. Can you post screen shots of the two intents so we can see the difference and suggest ways to improve them?

Comment: your Intent phrases should be comparatively different to one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have to set context and create separate intents. In **intent1** set **output context** as *intent1* and in **intent2** set **output context** as *intent2*, now create 2 separate intents like ***intent1-question*** with user says Number of user creating leads today? and with **input context** as *intent1* and create the other intent with the name ***intent2-question*** with user says Number of user creating leads today? and set the input context as **intent2**. please refer https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts